# How to convert MigLayout for JavaFX to an OSGi bundle so it will work inside an OSGi container?

Tags: javafx, osgi, apache-felix, equinox, miglayout

I'm trying to make an OSGi bundle that is a GUI written in JavaFX. My setup is as follows:

```
OS name: "linux", version: "3.8.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 10:22:22-0500)
```

I followed the instructions provided by the JavaFX Maven Plugin [to put the JavaFX runtime on the classpath](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/fix-classpath.html). I'm using apache felix as the OSGi container. All this together works rather nicely. (IE: I can create the JavaFX GUI as an OSGi bundle and it works!)

The problem that I have is with the MigLayout library for JavaFX. I'm using these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
  <artifactId>miglayout-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
  <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
  <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Neither of these are OSGi bundles, and the dependency upon them is causing a runtime error to occur in the application, specifically:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane from bundle 7 (client)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2489)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2333)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2301)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2154)
    at client.Gui.start(Gui.scala:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane from bundle 7 (client)
    at akka.osgi.impl.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.scala:49)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2546)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2487)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane not found by com.typesafe.akka.osgi [1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at akka.osgi.impl.BundleDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(BundleDelegatingClassLoader.scala:46)
    ... 18 more
```

Here is the sample fxml file that I'm trying to load, login.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane?>
<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="client.view.LoginView" fx:id="pane">
  <children>
    <Button text="Login" fx:id="loginButton" onAction="#login"/>
  </children>
</StackPane>
```

Please note that if I run this application outside of an OSGi container, the page loads fine. But inside the OSGi container it fails with the aforementioned stack trace. Also, if I comment out the import for the MigPane it loads just fine inside the OSGi container too. So the example below works fine inside the OSGi container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<!--<?import org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane?>-->
<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="client.view.LoginView" fx:id="pane">
  <children>
    <Button text="Login" fx:id="loginButton" onAction="#login"/>
  </children>
</StackPane>
```

I tried to solve this problem by using the `wrap` [command on Peter Kriens' bnd tool](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/CommandLine) to alter the MigLayout jar files so they will include the necessary OSGi meta data in the manifest file.

Commands:

```
// The original jar (the one specified in the aforementioned maven 
// dependency - which is not an OSGi bundle) is contained in the 
// wrap subdirectory.
$ java -jar bnd-2.1.0.jar wrap miglayout-core-4.2.jar wrap/miglayout-core-4.2.jar
$ java -jar bnd-2.1.0.jar wrap miglayout-javafx-4.2.jar wrap/miglayout-javafx-4.2.jar
```

miglayout-core-4.2.jar MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Bnd-LastModified: 1384015623755
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_29
Built-By: Mike
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: miglayout.core
Bundle-SymbolicName: miglayout.core
Bundle-Version: 0
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Export-Package: net.miginfocom.layout
Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122245
```

miglayout-javafx-4.2.jar MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Bnd-LastModified: 1384015600603
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_29
Built-By: Mike
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: miglayout.javafx
Bundle-SymbolicName: miglayout.javafx
Bundle-Version: 0
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Export-Package: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout;uses:="javafx.scene,javafx.
 scene.layout,net.miginfocom.layout",org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml;u
 ses:="javafx.beans,javafx.scene,net.miginfocom.layout,org.tbee.javafx.s
 cene.layout"
Import-Package: javafx.beans;resolution:=optional,javafx.collections;res
 olution:=optional,javafx.geometry;resolution:=optional,javafx.scene;res
 olution:=optional,javafx.scene.control;resolution:=optional,javafx.scen
 e.layout;resolution:=optional,javafx.scene.paint;resolution:=optional,j
 avafx.scene.shape;resolution:=optional,javafx.stage;resolution:=optiona
 l,net.miginfocom.layout;resolution:=optional
Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122245
```

But putting the resultant "bundle" in the OSGi container does not fix the problem. I get the same error.

I don't know what else to try so I can use the MigLayout library inside the OSGi container.

What do I need to do so I can use the MigLayout inside the OSGi container?

**EDIT**

Here is the code that loads the FXML. It is written in Scala.

```
package client

import _root_.javafx.application.Application
import _root_.javafx.stage.Stage
import _root_.javafx.scene.{Parent, Scene}
import _root_.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import client.view.{Login, Screen}

class Gui extends Application {
  def start(stage: Stage) {
    val initialScreen: Screen = Login
    stage.setTitle("GUI")
    val loader = new FXMLLoader
    loader.setLocation(initialScreen.url)
    try {
      val root: Parent = loader.load(initialScreen.inputStream).asInstanceOf[Parent]
      val scene: Scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600)
      scene.getStylesheets.add("/fxml/styles/styles.css")
      stage.setScene(scene)
      stage.show()
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace()
    }
  }

  override def stop() {
    System.out.println("Stopping JavaFX Application")
    Container.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Also, here is the Import-Packages that is defined for the client. The build is actually done with gradle using the scala and osgi plugins.

snippet of build.gradle:

```
def importPackages =
  '  akka.actor' +
    ', akka.actor.dungeon' +
    ', akka.event' +
    ', akka.osgi' +
    ', javafx.application' +
    ', javafx.beans' +
    ', javafx.collections' +
    ', javafx.fxml' +
    ', javafx.geometry' +
    ', javafx.scene' +
    ', javafx.scene.control' +
    ', javafx.scene.image' +
    ', javafx.scene.layout' +
    ', javafx.scene.paint' +
    ', javafx.scene.shape' +
    ', javafx.stage' +
    ', net.miginfocom.layout' +
    ', org.osgi.framework' +
    ', org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout' +
    ', org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml' +
    ', scala' +
    ', scala.collection' +
    ', scala.reflect' +
    ', scala.runtime'

jar {
  manifest {
    name = "client (OSGi bundle)"

    instruction 'Bundle-Vendor', 'Company'
    instruction 'Bundle-Description', 'Client (OSGi bundle)'

    instruction 'Private-Package', 'client'
    instruction 'Bundle-Activator', 'client.ClientActivator'

    instruction 'Import-Package', importPackages
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I modified the code that loads the fxml in accordance with tomsontom's suggestion to set the class loader. Here is the updated code:

snippet from build.gradle:

```
def importPackages =
  '  akka.actor' +
    ', akka.actor.dungeon' +
    ', akka.event' +
    ', akka.osgi' +
    ', javafx.application' +
    ', javafx.beans' +
    ', javafx.collections' +
    ', javafx.fxml' +
    ', javafx.geometry' +
    ', javafx.scene' +
    ', javafx.scene.control' +
    ', javafx.scene.image' +
    ', javafx.scene.layout' +
    ', javafx.scene.paint' +
    ', javafx.scene.shape' +
    ', javafx.stage' +
    ', net.miginfocom.layout' +
    ', org.osgi.framework' +
    ', org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout' +
    ', org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml' +
    ', scala' +
    ', scala.collection' +
    ', scala.reflect' +
    ', scala.runtime'
```

fxml loading code:

```
  def start(stage: Stage) {
    val initialScreen: Screen = Login
    stage.setTitle("GUI")
    val loader = new FXMLLoader
    loader.setClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader)
    loader.setLocation(initialScreen.url)
    try {
      val root: Parent = loader.load(initialScreen.inputStream).asInstanceOf[Parent]
      val scene: Scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600)
      scene.getStylesheets.add("/fxml/styles/styles.css")
      stage.setScene(scene)
      stage.show()
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable => t.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
```

But notice that now I get a similar but different error message when running the application in the OSGi container:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2489)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2333)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2301)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2154)
    at client.Gui.start(Gui.scala:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ExtensionManager$ExtensionManagerWiring.getClassByDelegation(ExtensionManager.java:873)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1553)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1484)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2546)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2487)
    ... 14 more
```

It's still generating a ClassNotFoundException. But this time, the stack trace doesn't include anything pertaining to which bundle the trace is coming from. Its a subtle difference, and I don't know what it means. Any ideas?

**EDIT 3**

I modified the OP to include the generated MANIFEST.MF file for both of the MigLayout dependencies after using the bnd command line utility.

**EDIT 4**

client.jar MANIFEST.MF 
(Note my package is really x.x.client rather than just client. But I've stripped the x.x. from the package name for SO. That is the reason for the line spacing discrepancy in this MANIFEST.MF file):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: client;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT";uses:=
 "akka.actor,akka.osgi,javafx.application,javafx.stage,org.osgi.framew
 ork,scala.reflect",client.controller;version="1.0.0.S
 NAPSHOT";uses:="akka.actor,akka.event,scala,scala.reflect,scala.runti
 me",client.message;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT";uses:="sc
 ala,scala.collection,scala.reflect",client.model;vers
 ion="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT";uses:="scala.reflect",client.vie
 w;version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT";uses:="scala,scala.collection,scala.reflec
 t"
Private-Package: client
Tool: Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
Bundle-Name: client (OSGi bundle)
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Bundle-Vendor: Company
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Bnd-LastModified: 1384035615000
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: client.ClientActivator
Bundle-Description: Client (OSGi bundle)
Bundle-SymbolicName: client
Import-Package: akka.actor;version="[2.2,3)",akka.event;version="[2.2,
 3)",akka.osgi;version="[2.2,3)",javafx.application,javafx.collections
 ,javafx.fxml,javafx.scene,javafx.stage,org.osgi.framework;version="[1
 .7,2)",scala;version="[2.10,3)",scala.collection;version="[2.10,3)",s
 cala.reflect;version="[2.10,3)",scala.runtime;version="[2.10,3)",net.
 miginfocom.layout,org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml,org.tbee.javafx.s
 cene.layout,javafx.scene.layout,javafx.scene.image,javafx.scene.contr
 ol,javafx.scene.shape,javafx.scene.paint,javafx.geometry,javafx.beans
 ,akka.actor.dungeon;version="[2.2,3)"
```

**EDIT 5**

I created a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/axiopisty/scala-actors-javafx-osgi-demo) that you can download to see the problem. As currently checked in, this project should run right away after you check it out if you follow the instructions in the file README.txt.

If you want to see the problem I'm experiencing with the MigLayout library, edit the file `client/src/main/resources/fxml/login.fxml` by uncommenting the import for the MigPane. Rebuild the project, copy the newly created client-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to the `app/bundle/` directory, clear the felix-cache directory with `$ rm -rf app/felix-cache/` and then restart the felix launcher from within the `app` directory with the command `$ java -jar bin/felix.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99% sure in fxml your problem is that you have not set the correct classloader. Please show your fxml loading code

Comment: Ok i saw you updated and yes you need to call setClassloader on the fxmlloader instance. If you think about it your code has to fail in OSGi because FXMLLoader is in the extclassloader which naturally does not know about the migpane in your OSGi bundle

Comment: Which class loader would I pass to setClassloader? Where does it come from in an OSGi bundle?

Comment: The one which holds the loading code has to have a dependency on migpane and then pass this one. You need to think like how would you configure your bundle if you implement the stuff in the fxml file in a java class, so you should also import all javafx package! You get the classloader which getClass().getClassloader()

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think this is almost solved, but its still causing a problem. Please see I updated the OP again.

Comment: You don't show the manifest of your ui bundle. I'd suggest to start with pure java/scala and then add fxml to it

Comment: Updated OP to contain manifest.mf for the UI bundle. As for starting with pure java/scala, and then adding fxml to it. Please note that this entire example already works (even with fxml) and without the addition of manually specifying the class loader, if only I don't use the MigLayout dependency. The only problem is accessing the MigLayout dependency, specifically: org.tbee.javafx.scene.layout.fxml.MigPane

Comment: I edited the OP to now contain a link to a project on GitHub that demonstrates the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have corresponding Import-Package statements in your UI bundle. The easiest way to create these is to use the [maven bundle plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) in the pom of your UI bundle.

Wether you use the bundle plugin check the resulting Manifest to make sure all nevessary Import-Package statements are present.

Comment: Yes, I should have included that in the OP. I do have import statements in the client bundle. I'm confused why it's not working.

Comment: The only other idea is that maybe the midlayout core does not have the Import-Package statement and the exception occurs in a miglayout core class that of course uses its own classloader.

Comment: Wouldn't that produce a different error message, something about not being able to wire the bundles together?

Comment: An error about failed resolution would occur if there is an Import-Package statement but there is no bundle exporting it. If the Import-Package statement is missing but the package is used anyways then there will be a runtime ClassNotFoundException like in your case.